# Making a simple RSS feed with jquery/ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, rss

I'm in need of some help, I want to make a simple rss feed that reads off of a website like arstechnica. I've researched and looked around for the past couple of hours but I'm a little confused on the proper way to do something like this. I'm currently attempting to do it how I would access json data. This may be entirely wrong but, below is sample code I have so far. I thank you for your time.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
//rss
function LoadRss()
{
var feed;
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    url: "http://feeds.arstechnica.com/arstechnica/index?format=xml",
    dataType: 'xml',
    contentType: 'application/xml',
    success: function(data){
    $('#feed').html(data);
    }

});
});
}

LoadRss()
setInterval( LoadRss, 30000);
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="feed"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you not missing one argument?

```
contentType: 'application/xml',
```

Please try it.

And don't forget about

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
```

so you can use `jQuery.ajax()`.

Still you will be probably struggling with `CORS` Cross-Origin, so maybe instead you could use `<iframe>`?

and

```
location.reload()
```

in

```
setInterval(function(){location.reload()}, 30000);
```

Like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    setInterval(function(){location.reload()}, 30000);
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe style="width: 800px; height: 800px;" src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/ArsTechnica?format=xml"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Made some edits for it, doesn't seem to solve it but those are definitely things that should have been there. Thank you

Comment: @PatrickO maybe it's because of Cross Origin problem. It is difficult to get RSS from another website like you are trying to do. Good luck anyway.

Comment: I will research the cross origin problem. iFrames are something I feel dumb for not considering, thanks for helping me something see and solution thats real simple.